# Using STM32 with ESP8266 to get radio stream and play it

Tags: arduino, audio, stm32, arm, esp8266

I am using STM32F407 board to communicate with ESP8266 using AT commands. Goal is to have STM32 tell ESP8266 to go to a live radio link then get the stream and put it through a VS1053 and out to a speaker. Now I am stuck because most examples online show ESP being used by itself to connect to live radios. I just need some hints as to what to learn next or what should I be looking at? Is it simply a case of streaming the audio data from the website and passing it to VS1053? If so how?